# add a "0" with a condition to the beginning of a string in R it is different to "Add zeros to R because it has a condition"

Tags: r, string-length

I have this data frame:

```
bloqueados$HoraLlamada<- as.character(c(83048, 163112, 115929, 123632, 114541,  72807 163626, 130051,  81645, 121639))
```

If their the name of characters of each row is 5 I need to add a "0" at the beginning of the string. I am trying these code, but it is adding a "0" to every row:

```
for (i in bloqueados$HoraLlamada){
    if(nchar(bloqueados$HoraLlamada)==5){
        bloqueados$HoraLlamada2<- paste("0",bloqueados$HoraLlamada)
    }else{
        bloqueados$HoraLlamada2<-paste(bloqueados$HoraLlamada)
    }
}
```

Comment: You didn't use `i` inside the loop

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[r]+add+leading+zeros

Comment: `sprintf` to the rescue again.

Comment: `str_pad()` from `stringr` and you can skip that `for` loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several possible approaches to solve this problem have been described in the comments. Here's another one. It uses the `stri_pad_left()` function from the `stringi` package.

```
nums <-  as.character(c(83048, 163112, 115929, 123632, 114541,  72807, 163626, 130051,  81645, 121639))
library(stringi)
stri_pad_left(nums, pad="0", width = 6)
#[1] "083048" "163112" "115929" "123632" "114541" "072807" "163626" "130051" "081645" "121639"
```